# The placeholder variable does not update during iteration

Tags: c++, data-structures

I am trying to solve an online coding challenge that is asking me to find the left-most digit in a string and return that value.  This is what is expected:

```
leftDigit("TrAdE2W1n95!") ➞ 2

leftDigit("V3r1ta$") ➞ 3

leftDigit("U//DertHe1nflu3nC3") ➞ 1

leftDigit("J@v@5cR1PT") ➞ 5
```

And in my attempt, I made the placeholder variable = 0 to see whether the value is being updated or not:

```
int leftDigit(std::string str) {
    int left_most = 0;
    std::vector<int> digits (0,9);
    
    for(int i = 0; i < str.size(); i++){
        if(std::find(digits.begin(), digits.end(), str[i]) != digits.end()){
            left_most = str[i];
            break;
        }
    }
    return left_most;
}
```

However, my code only passes 1 test so the issue is with my logic:

```
test1
FAILED: Expected: equal to 2
Actual: 0
test2
FAILED: Expected: equal to 3
Actual: 0
test3
FAILED: Expected: equal to 1
Actual: 0
test4
FAILED: Expected: equal to 5
Actual: 0
test5
Test Passed
test6
FAILED: Expected: equal to 8
Actual: 0
```

**Update**

Per a recommendation from a user, I've made the following changes:

```
int leftDigit(std::string str) {
    char left_most;
    auto pos = str.find_first_of("0123456789");
    
    if(pos == std::string::npos){
        left_most = pos;
    }
    return left_most;
}
```

However, the output is still the same.

Comment: What do you think the statement `std::vector<int> digits (0,9)` does? If you want to take this approach, you may find [`std::iota`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota) helpful here.

Comment: FWIW, `auto pos = str.find_first_of("123456789");` will do what you want.  You just need to check if `pos == std::string::npos` to tell if it actually found a digit or not.

Comment: @NathanOliver This is what I did: `if(pos == std::string::npos){left_most = pos;}` for the if statement.  It still returns the same output.

Comment: @NathanOliver Check the edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code fails because you are not populating the `vector` correctly.

1. `std::vector<int> digits (0,9);` declares a `vector` named `digits` that contains 0 elements of value `9`, which is not what you want.  You wanted a `vector` with 10 elements ranging from `0..9` instead.  In C++11 and later, you can create that range using `std::vector<int> digits {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};` instead.
2. Even if you were filling the `vector` correctly, you are searching for an ASCII character in a `vector` of integers, so `std::find()` will always return `digits.end()`, as `0` does not match `'0'` (`48`), `1` does not match `'1'` (`49`), etc.

The easiest way to fix the code is to just get rid of the `vector` altogether:

```cpp
static const std::string digits = "0123456789";

char leftDigit(const std::string &str) {
    for(int i = 0; i < str.size(); ++i){
        if (digits.find(str[i]) != std::string::npos){
            return str[i];
        }
    }
    return '\0';
}
```

Alternative, get rid of the loop, too:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>

char leftDigit(const std::string &str) {
    auto iter = std::find_if(str.begin(), str.end(),
        [](char ch){ return std::isdigit(static_cast<unsigned char>(ch)); }
    }
    return (iter != str.end()) ? *iter : '\0';
}
```

Or simpler:

```cpp
char leftDigit(const std::string &str) {
    size_t index = str.find_first_of("0123456789");
    return (index != std::string::npos) ? str[index] : '\0';
}
```

Comment: Instead of just rewriting code for me, you could've just showed me how to improve my existing code.

Answer (score 2):

This is because your vector is composed of int and in the string you're looking for char. The int value of '0' is not 0 but 48 so you have to add 48 to your str[i].